# HP 1920-24G VLAN Configuration

Tags: vlan

[image]

In the configuration above, I already configure VLAN10, VLAN20 and VLAN30. 
Question, how to configure routing between VLAN? like VLAN10 can also access to VLAN20 and VLAN30 back and forth?

Thanks

Comment: Also, after creating VLAN20 and VLAN30, computers that are connected on these VLAN's doesn't have IP address

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the user guide and nowhere does it mention inter-vlan routing:
https://www.manualagent.com/hp/1920-24g-switch/users-manual/download

From the following link (1920-48g) https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/62cs27/inter_vlan_routing_for_hpe_192048g/

"Short of the story is, you don't need routes. Just create the two VLANs that you want, both with IP addresses in separate subnets, and you will be able to ping each other."

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I just created VLANs with both with IP address in separate subnets just like in the photo above. The problem is VLAN10 cannot see pc connected on VLAN20. And BTW, I put another DSL router on VLAN20 with ip address of 172.168.10.10 as gateway, then the pc that are assign to VLAN20 gets the ip address of 172.168.10.11 gw: 172.168.10.10. And still can't communicate on each VLAN

Comment: I updated my post. After creating VLAN20 and VLAN30, computers that are connected on these VLAN's doesn't have IP address

Comment: @aimbots issue could be firmware, on the following link for example they  had to downgrade firmware to get routing working  https://community.hpe.com/t5/Web-and-Unmanaged/InterVLAN-routing-on-a-V1910-series-switch/td-p/5947659

Comment: I hope firmware downgrade would work

Comment: @aimbots what do you mean? did you test it out already?

Comment: Yes, I've made several testings.

Comment: Yes, I've made several testings already. Reset everything and started all over again. 
Creating VLAN10 (192.168.10.10), VLAN20 (192.168.20.10), VLAN30(192.168.30.10). 
Connecting my isp router (192.168.1.1) to VLAN10, then VLAN10 pc gets the ip address of 192.168.1.2 gw: 192.168.1.1 the same as pc connected to VLAN20 and VLAN30
Now, I’m connecting another ISP router address of 192.168.254.254 to port9 on VLAN20. But it seems pc connected to VLAN20 still gets ip address of 192.168.1.1 from VLAN10. And even if I disconnect the second ISP router on port9, still gets ip address from ISP1

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a router with an interface in each VLAN, for example 192.168.x.1, which then provides routing between the subnets. All hosts then needs to be assigned that IP as the default gateway. The router also needs to have a default route pointing at the DSL router. You could do this as "router-on-a-stick" internally in the switch, and from what I've read the 1920 should be able to do routing, provided you have a limited amount of routes and they are static.

Comment: The 19xx series are L3 switches.